# Euler's Formula and Linear Difference Equation Solution

Tags: trigonometry, recurrence-relations, substitution

Can Euler's Formula be generalized for an arbitrary function of $i$?  In other words, is it the case that $e^{f(i)n} = cos(n) + f(i)sin(n)$?

The solution to the homogeneous linear difference equation $y[n + 1] = -y[n]$ obtained by the characteristic polynomial method is $y = A(−i)^n + B(i)^n$.  Can I start to arrive at the real solution by rewriting this in the following way? $$y = A(−i)^n + B(i)^n$$$$\implies y = Ae^{ln(−i)n} + Be^{ln(i)n}$$$$\implies y = A(cos(n) + ln(−i)sin(n)) + B(cos(n) + ln(i)sin(n))$$$$\implies y = Acos(n) − A\frac{i\pi}{2}sin(n) + Bcos(n) + B\frac{iπ}{2}sin(n)$$

If this is all valid, how can I get from $y = Acos(n) − A\frac{i\pi}{2}sin(n) + Bcos(n) + B\frac{iπ}{2}sin(n)$ to the real solution $y = C(-1)^n$?

**Edit:**  Using Neat Math's comment, I get $$y = A(−i)^n + B(i)^n$$$$\implies y = Ae^{-\frac{\pi n}{2}i} + Be^{\frac{\pi n}{2}i}$$$$\implies y = A(cos(-\frac{\pi n}{2}) + isin(-\frac{\pi n}{2})) + B(cos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) + isin(\frac{\pi n}{2}))$$$$\implies y = Acos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) - Aisin(\frac{\pi n}{2}) + Bcos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) + Bisin(\frac{\pi n}{2})$$$$\implies D = A + B, E = Bi - Ai$$$$\implies Dcos(\frac{\pi n}{2}) + Esin(\frac{\pi n}{2})$$

Is this just some trig trick away from $y = C(-1)^n$?

Comment: No you are making things too complicated. Just write $i=\exp (i \frac{\pi}{2}), -i = \exp (i (-\frac{\pi}{2}))$ then the imaginary parts will cancel out in the general form $y = A(−i)^n + B(i)^n$.

Comment: @NeatMath Awesome, edited post.

Comment: Hi sorry I wasn't reading carefully. If your equation is $y(n+1) = - y(n)$ then the characteristics equation is linear: $\lambda + 1=0$, and the root is $-1$. If the roots are $i$ and $-i$ that means your linear difference equation should be $y(n+2)=-y(n)$. Which one is correct?

Comment: @NeatMath Ahh, good catch, the whole confusion was over that error.